# How to text wrap properly in HTML?

Tags: html, text

Currently, I'm trying to figure out a clean way to insert images into my blog. The editor does not support text wrap for some reason, so I'm trying to use HTML to text wrap.

It looks fine in the actual blog post: http://www.jerielng.com/apps/blog/show/39057864-book-review-a-dance-with-dragons

But on another page, it looks like this, where it overlaps onto other text:
http://www.jerielng.com/apps/blog/

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<p style="text-align: left; "><font color="#333333"><span><img src="http://www.jerielng.com/A_Dance_With_Dragons_US.jpg" class="fw_image_freewebs fwSizeProp" style="margin: 5px" width="167" align="left" border="0" height="248"/>Coming off from a disappointing fourth installment, </span><i>A Dance with Dragons</i><span> had much room for improvement, and George R. R. Martin certainly provided for a better story this time. I guess it&#8217;s inevitable that this book would be better since the series&#8217; three most beloved characters (Jon Snow, Daenerys Targaryen, and Tyrion Lannister) return after being left out last time. But, besides that, we get to see the stories develop more progress, building up to something much bigger. If you&#8217;ve read the other books in the series, or if you&#8217;re a fantasy reader at all, </span><i>A Dance with Dragons</i><span> is certainly worth the read despite the time it takes to finish it.</span></font></p><p><font color="#333333">&#160;</font></p><p><font color="#333333">Of course, I won&#8217;t say this novel is perfect. As much as it has improved from <i>A Feast for Crows</i>, this one still has some of that same stagnant feeling in which the characters don&#8217;t seem to be going anywhere specific. Then again, a good bit of the cast has (spoiler alert) already been killed off by this point, so the rest just seem to be meandering around. Overall, it seems to be holding off until the sixth and seventh books, where the major events will finally conclude the story. However, that&#8217;s not to say absolutely nothing happens. As I mentioned above, the story development this time is much stronger than in the past.</font></p><p><font color="#333333">&#160;</font></p><p><font color="#333333">What is also interesting about this book is that, towards the end, it begins to include all the characters again. In the fourth book and at least the first half of this one, Martin had separated the storylines by geography, not by chronology as he normally does, so the cast did feel a little thin for a while. Consequently, we are treated to that same experience that we had gotten used to, and hopefully this will continue on throughout the rest of the series.</font></p><p><font color="#333333">&#160;</font></p><p><font color="#333333">Putting aside the noticeable features of this particular novel, we still find the same elements of the story in <i>A Song of Ice and Fire</i> that we&#8212;or, at least, I&#8212;enjoy most about George R. R. Martin&#8217;s work. As usual, the prose flows beautifully with the imagery as detailed as ever, and the action and cliffhangers remain just as suspenseful. Yes, I&#8217;d like to see how the series concludes over the last few books, but as a standalone work, <i>A Dance with Dragons</i> did not disappoint.</font></p>
```

This may be the CSS for this paragraph. I'm not sure where to find the exact one because the program doesn't provide it for some reason.

```
#fw-mainColumn {border:6px grey !important; background: white !important; padding: 11px !important;}
#fw-mainColumn .fw-paragraph {background: Gainsboro  !important; color: black !important; border: 1px dotted black !important;}
```

Comment: Please also show your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.
Every div with the class 'post' is a new blog post (a.k.a. row)

HTML:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="message">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.post{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

div.image {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

div.message {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
```

The post class needs at least a width. On some browsers even also a height.
The overflow makes the div align around the image and message.

An other/older way to make the post class align around the image and message, is by using this in the CSS of the post class (instead of the overflow):

```
clear: both;
```

This ensures that the post class ignores all previous set float values.

EDIT:

BTW: clean up your HTML
At this moment, it's quite hard to read as it's all on one line. But I did notice some things:

- Whats with all the span's?
  You only need a span if you want to format a certain piece of text.
  Just place the text inside the `<p>`
- `<i>` should be replaced with `<em>`
  I won't go into detail about this, but it has to do with Style Validity
- Try to place your CSS as much as possible in an external file, which you load in the page's header.
  Too much inline CSS will become unreadable + a lot of extra work if you want to change 1 thingy.